# Pandas Series identifying number of consecutive consonants

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Given a `Series` of strings, I'm trying to calculate a new `Series` which contains the highest consecutive count of consonants in the original string, ignoring spaces.

For example, given `df['names']`, I'd like to determine `df['max_consonants']` like below:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
               names max_consonants
0       will hunting              2
1       sean maguire              1
2     gerald lambeau              2
3   chuckie sullivan              2
4    mike krzyzewski              5
```

Outside of `pandas`, I am able to do this using the `re` module, like so:

```
In [2]: def max_consonants(s):
             return max(len(i) for i in re.findall(r'[^aeiou ]+', s))

In [3]: max_consonants('mike krzyzewski')
Out[3]: 5
```

I know I can use `pd.Series.apply` to use the `max_consonants` function on a `Series`, but it is not vectorized.  I am working with data containing 2-3mm rows/names, so I am looking for the most efficient solution.

Is there a more elegant solution native to `pandas` that would allow me to take advantage of vectorization?

Comment: `[^aeiou ]` also matches `§`, `”`, etc., not just consonants.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Good point.  Fortunately my database does not contain any special characters, but for the sake of completeness, I can change the regex pattern to `'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+'`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, it should also work for special characters because of the `\W`. But please note, that `\W` also catches numbers, so if you also want to split on those, you need to add `0-9` to the regex used by split:

```
df['names'].str.split(r'[AaEeIiOoUu\W]', expand=True).fillna('').applymap(len).max(axis='columns')
```

With the test data:

```
raw="""idx             names  max_consonants
0       will hunting              2
1       sean maguire              1
2     gerald lambeau              2
3   chuckie sullivan              2
4    mike krzyzewski              5
5    mike krzyzewski12345678      5
"""
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep='\s{2,}', index_col=[0])
```

This evaluates to:

```
idx
0    2
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    5
5    8
dtype: int64
```

The intermediate result before the `applymap` looks like this btw:

```
Out[89]: 
      0   1   2      3    4         5  6  7
idx                                        
0     w  ll   h     nt   ng                
1     s       n      m    g            r   
2     g   r  ld      l   mb                
3    ch  ck               s        ll  v  n
4     m   k      krzyz  wsk                
5     m   k      krzyz  wsk  12345678
```

Note on the performance: I would expect `.mapapply(len)` to be translated to efficient C++ operations, but can't verify it with my data. In case you get performance problems with this solution, you can try a variant in which you perform everything up to the `applymap`, replace the applymap by a loop over the columns and perform `.str.len()`. Which would roughly look like this:

```
df_consonant_strings= df['names'].str.split(r'[AaEeIiOoUu\W]', expand=True).fillna('')
ser_max= None
for col in df_consonant_strings.columns:
    ser_col= df_consonant_strings[col].str.len()
    if ser_max is None:
        ser_max= ser_col
    else:
        ser_max= ser_max.where(ser_max>ser_col, ser_col)
# now ser_max contains the desired maximum length of consonant substrings
```